# Moving git repo from public_html/stage folder to root public_html/

Tags: linux, git, github

On my linux server I have a website running in public_html/stage which i cloned from guthub to /stage folder.

Now after the development is over i want to move this folder to root i.e public_html folder, making sure that its sync with my repo.

I tried to cp all /stage files to the root directory but the main folder /app was not copied.

Pls guide me how can I move this staging to production.

Also please let me know what is the standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

They're just files, you can copy them.

```
cd /path/to/public_html
cp -r stage/* .
```

Make sure not to copy your Git repository, the `.git` directory.  If you did, that would turn `public_html/` into a Git repository.

If you *do* want to move the whole repository into `public_html`, again it's just files.  Everything git needs is in `stage/.git/`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to my problem, but not sure if what I did is a standard way. But anyhow it resolved my problem. So here is what i did...

I initialized an empty repo in public_html folder and then added remote to my github repo and finally fetch all code from the repo.

> ```
> $ git init
> $ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
> $ git fetch --all
> $ git reset --hard origin/master
> ```

So now my project is working fine at the root of the website and is in sync with the repo. So everytime I do some local changes to my repo I only need to pull them from repo

> ```
> $ git pull origin master
> ```

And thats all!

Comment: There's plenty of ways to do it.  You can replace `git fetch --all` and `git reset --hard origin/master` with `git pull origin master`.  That will do the `fetch`, make a `master` branch from `origin/master` and check out `master`.